# Python: Normalizing eigenfunctions over the range of the for loop

Tags: python, math, linear-algebra, physics, eigenvector

I am trying to plot the probability density of a wavefunction, however with my current code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as LA

for x in range(0,steps+1):
     ...
     w,v=LA.eig(H)
     probdensity = v@np.conj(v.T)
```

I am getting normalized wavefunctions for each step such that the probability density is 1 at every point such that the total probability is 'steps', how can I obtain eigenfunctions that are normalized against every other calculated eigenfunction in the loop?

What I want from this is for the sum of probability densities of every step to be equal to 1. Any help would be gratly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> X = [[ 1., -1.,  2.],
...      [ 2.,  0.,  0.],
...      [ 0.,  1., -1.]]
>>> X_normalized = preprocessing.normalize(X, norm='l2')

>>> X_normalized
array([[ 0.40..., -0.40...,  0.81...],
       [ 1.  ...,  0.  ...,  0.  ...],
       [ 0.  ...,  0.70..., -0.70...]])
```

> https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#preprocessing-normalization